# Mousewheel event in as3 scrolls flash and html. is there a way to stop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript, mousewheel

I'm using SWFWheel to get the mousewheel events in actionscript 3, and I have a small flash window amongst a full html page that needs a scrollbar. The flash scrolls properly, but the whole HTML page scrolls with it. How can I disable scroll to html when over the flash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally posted at http://www.spikything.com/blog/?s=mousewheeltrap

Now at http://code.google.com/p/mousewheeltrap/

I'm using this solution on some games for Facebook.
Works like a charm.

Comment: This took all a 3 minutes to implement and it works perfectly. Thanks a million!

Comment: Didn't know about allowBrowserScroll(). Is it cross-browser?

Comment: Never mind. Just noticed you (or spikything if that isn't you) injected that from within ActionScript.

Comment: it is safe. browsers can handle this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with Chrome. Look for BlastedMouseWheelBlock for a Chrome/Max-related hack. Still not perfect though!

Answer (score 2):

You should listen for scroll events on the DOM element that contains the Flash embed code. Then in the handler, you prevent the default behavior.

For instance with jQuery, you can use the [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event handler and within it you would call [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on the event.

```
<div id="flashContainer">
    <object ... />
</div>

$('#flashContainer').scroll(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This is essentially what the above code is doing, so thanks for your answer!